# MERN React/Redux/MongoDB solid isomorphic boilerplate with authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, redux

I have a task to build a boilerplate for our future web applications using `ReactJS`/`Redux`/`MongoDB`/`Node` (`MERN`) as a basic technology stack.

Basically all of our web applications are dashboards, with a login landing page (with register/login/forgot pwd/reset pwd). The boilerplate should be driven by microservices and needs to support both web and mobile integration (using `ReactJS Native`). Both client and server will call my APIs, that needs to be available also as REST services for integration. The app should be isomorphic as a best practice today.

I decided to start from [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example), but as we can see the its landing page, it may be outdated (was written in June 2015).

The basic structure of my project is being tought as the following modules:

api: The API services (REST) 
auth: To handle authentication
server: Server 
client: client
models: Mongo models and database access
static: Static files (images, etc.)

These are the modules I'm planning to use (mainly from react-redux-universal-hot-example):

- React (basic)
- React Router (to route)
- Express (basic)
- Babel (basic)
- Webpack (basic)
- Webpack Dev Middleware (for development)
- Webpack Hot Middleware (for development)
- Redux (for data update)
- Redux Dev Tools (for development)
- React Router Redux Redux/React Router bindings.
- ESLint (for code styling)
- redux-form (to help with forms)
- lru-memoize (to form validation)
- multireducer (to build a key based reducer)
- style-loader  (to work with css and sass)
- bootstrap-sass-loader (to easily customize bootstrap colors)
- font-awesome-webpack (to easily customize fa colors)
- react-helmet (to manage meta tags)
- webpack-isomorphic-tools (for isomorphic app)
- mocha (for unit testing)

Not present in the react-redux-universal-hot-example, I would addÇ

- mongoose (for Mongo access)
- Auth0, JWT and passport (for authentication)

From the above path, I have the following doubts:

a) Are the modules listed above updated as for today ? Should I use something newer to the given list ?

b) Is react-redux-universal-hot-example a good starting point or shall I look for something newer, better organized or just more up to date ?

c) Is my modules/directories structure correct ? Any comments on that ?

d) Generally speaking, is this a solid base to start from ?

b) Is there something missing that would help

Answer (score 0):

check out:

https://github.com/bertho-zero/react-redux-universal-hot-example#server-side-data-fetching

This is an updated fork. It has a lot of things that you want, and more. I am using it myself and I am mighty impressed.

Answer (score 0):

i've updated it further. soon to put in webpack 4 and babel 7, working on it...also going to swap out react loadable for universal component, for SSR+component splitting two in one far more elegantly than loader.  i cleaned up the nav so it's symmetrical on open and close, instead of opening full and closing halfway up the p0age all sketchy. updated the semantic ui pack inside, added some config for circleci and travis ci...

https://github.com/kaigouthro/react-redux-semantic-ui

https://react-redux-semantic-hotplate.herokuapp.com/templatek

as of this date, it's the furthest along fork i believe. 
it's really a badass kit.

i'm going to touch it up some more, but i'm starting something fresh, making a new frankenstein that will be a spiritual successor, pieced together out of the best parts of the top boilers, and will include more auth, and libraries for animation, transitions, and layout choices. that'll take a couple months. but, in the meantime.. enjoy the update.